# Magento 2.3.5 extend \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I'm able to add layered navigation to a custom page, but if I try to extend \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer class i've got this exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: -1015 in /mnt/vdb/vhosts/emlineamoto.com/subdomains/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php on line 302
```

Here the code i use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Outlet" type="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layerResolver" xsi:type="object">Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Resolver</argument>
            <argument name="filterList" xsi:type="object">searchFilterList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Resolver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layersPool" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="outlet" xsi:type="string">Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Outlet</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Context" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collectionProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider</argument>
            <argument name="stateKey" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey</argument>
            <argument name="collectionFilter" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Outlet">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer\Context</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

and class:

```
<?php
namespace Bileamara\SpecialCollection\Model\Layer;

class Outlet extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{   
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('real_stock',1);
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work.

So I share the code, maybe will be helpfull for some one.

VENDOR/MODULE/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Outlet" type="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterList" xsi:type="object">spcFilterList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="spcFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet\FilterableAttributeList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layer" xsi:type="object">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet\Context" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collectionProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider</argument>
            <argument name="stateKey" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey</argument>
            <argument name="collectionFilter" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet\Context</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Outlet\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layersPool" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category</item>
                <item name="search" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</item>
                <item name="outlet" xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer\Outlet</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

VENDOR/MODULE/Controller/Outelt/View

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Outlet;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    private $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->layerResolver->create('outlet');

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

VENDOR/MODULE/Model/Layer/Outlet.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Layer;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel;

class Outlet extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param StateFactory $layerStateFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('ATTRIBUTE_CODE', 'ATTRIBUTE_VALUE');
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Here I've filtered collection by custom attribute to have a special collection page.

Using "addFieldToFilter" allows you to show configurable products that have children with attributes corresponding to the selection.

VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/module_outlet_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Outlet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Outlet" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Outlet\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                        <item name="addToWishlistLink" xsi:type="string">.action.towishlist</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"
                       name="category.product.addto.wishlist" as="wishlist" before="compare"
                       template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\AddToWishlist" name="category.product.list.additional.wishlist_addto" template="Magento_Wishlist::addto.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is your custom collection page!